# Visual Studio DB "Schema View" throws a ComException

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When trying to open an item, such as a stored procedure, in the DB Schema View in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, an error dialog box appears with a ComException.

What's the cause? How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, unload the project (not the entire solution!), then reload it.